# Split line with with several spaces

Tags: java, string, split

I have a text file in which I have to take line by line.

for each line I have to cut my string and put it in a table.

My separator is space.

Example of String:

```
22/03/2013 00h00    9940    10200    10260    10190    10030    10060
```

Example of result:

```
[22/03/2013 00h00,  9940, 10200, 10260, 10190, 10030, 10060]
```

my problem is that in my file, my separator varies from one line to another

Example:

```
22/03/2013 00h00 9940    10200    10260    10190    10030    10060
22/03/2013 01h00    9970 9900    9970    9850 9830    9740 
22/03/2013 02h00      9630      9750      10010      10100    10040    10010
```

How I could cut my string ?

Comment: You can say myString.split(" "); Which will return a String array. You'd have to know what data is in what order though. Some clarification is needed though.

Comment: @hdtsn my pb is in know how space separate my string

Comment: Do you want your first two space separated strings as the same element?

Comment: Why do you use a separator that is included in the elements it's meant to separate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex

```
str.split("(?<!/\\d{4}) +");
```

Comment: ok, but i want to put this line in my table :22/03/2013 00h00 and there is a space ??

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that `String.split()` takes a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/). You can split on multiple whitespaces thus:

```
myString.split("\\s+");
```

This uses the [character class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html) `\s`, representing any whitespace character (space, tab etc.)

It's not clear how well your data rows are defined in terms of spaces. Your best bet may be to split on whitespace as above, then take the first *2* elements and handle them as a date/time. e.g.

```
String[] results = myString.split("\\s+");
String datetime = results[0] + " " + results[1];
```

(checking for those result elements existing, etc.)

Comment: ok, but i want to put this line in my table :22/03/2013 00h00 and there is a space ??

Answer (score 0):

Something like should work for you:

```
String str = "22/03/2013 00h00 9940    10200    10260    10190    10030    10060 " +
    "22/03/2013 01h00    9970 9900    9970    9850 9830    9740 " + 
    "22/03/2013 02h00      9630      9750      10010      10100    10040    10010";

// split string into individual records
String[] rows = str.split("\\s+(?=\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4} )");

// now split each row into columns (combine first 2 columns into 1)
for (String r: rows)
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(r.split("(?<!\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4})\\s+")));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[22/03/2013 00h00, 9940, 10200, 10260, 10190, 10030, 10060]
[22/03/2013 01h00, 9970, 9900, 9970, 9850, 9830, 9740]
[22/03/2013 02h00, 9630, 9750, 10010, 10100, 10040, 10010]
```

**Explanation:** First regex to split by 1 or more space/newline characters if it is followed by a date in nn/nn/nnnn format `\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}`.

Second regex is to split columns by 1 or more space/newline characters if it is NOT preceded by a date in the same format thus ignoring very first space after date.

Comment: I think some explanation would be useful here, given the regexp functions being used